# How do I make such a page that opens different link in web (PC) and different in mobile (phones)?

Tags: javascript, html, css, html5, css3

I am building a website that looks beautiful in Web but worst in mobiles. I want to build the same site but different designing for mobile. Whenever user opens `site.com` then it auto redirect to `m.site.com` OR `site.com/mob` only if on mobile.

Comment: Whatever solution you choose, please let the user explicitly switch between the mobile and desktop version of the site. It's quite frustrating when the mobile version has less functionality than the desktop site, or when resizing my desktop browser window to 200px messes up the layout. The user knows best what they need.

Comment: When they will open in mobile it will say "Please download our app", thats what i want. Because its a gaming site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 ways to implement a mobile website:

1. [Responsive Web Design](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/responsive-design): Serves the same HTML code on the same URL regardless of the users’ device (desktop, tablet, mobile, non-visual browser), but can render the display differently (i.e., “respond”) based on the screen size. Responsive design is Google’s recommended design pattern.
2. [Dynamic serving](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/dynamic-serving): Uses the same URL regardless of device, but generates a different version of HTML for different device types based on what the server knows about the user’s browser.
3. [Separate URLs](https://developers.google.com/webmasters/mobile-sites/mobile-seo/separate-urls): Serves different code to each device, and on separate URLs. This configuration tries to detect the users’ device, then redirects to the appropriate page using HTTP redirects] along with the Vary HTTP header.

You can choose any method suitable to your requirements and project. There are both pros and cons of each, so I will recommend spending time on the decision.

Comment: @AhmadTaha these are the only way, not an option. You can develop the mobile website. you can make the redirect to m. or any other folder on your website using .htaccess file or global.cs file in asp.net case

Comment: Oh sorry i didnt saw the 2,3. Really sorry. And thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

Read more about [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol). You probably should take into account the [`User-Agent:` header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent).

It would be different on mobiles and on desktops (and would vary from one browser to the next).

A clever user would probably be able to fake it, but few people do that.